# Best way to save variables between postbacks asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How can I save variables in asp.net between postback?
I'm using HttpContext.Current.Items but it always disposes after postback is there any other option to do that?

Comment: Session, ViewState, Cache. find details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx#S9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ViewState["YourVariable"] = "123";
```

ViewState collection is mean for this purpose, in above example YourVariable is a variable whoes value you want to save and 123 is value of this variable.

ViewState is accessible within the scope of page. If you want to have values between different pages you can use sessions like ViewState["YourVariable"] = "123";

Comment: But ViewState is whole the time sended between client>server<client
And i need something that i can access from another class.

Comment: ViewState is accessible within the scope of page. If you want to have values between different pages you can use sessions like ViewState["YourVariable"] = "123";

Comment: you meant: If you want to have values between different pages you can use sessions like Session[YourVariable"] = "123";

Comment: Using ViewState technique will also add to the size of the page, so it's better to use Session variables. Just make sure to remove the Session variable when it's no longer needed

Answer (score 12):

If your variable is not serializable or you do not want the client to be able to read its value => use inProc Session

If your variable is serializable and you do not want the client to be able to read its value => use database Session

if your variable is serializable, and you can live with the client reading its value, and it should only live during the postbacks sequence in the scope of the page => you should use ViewState.