# vb.net viewstate vs public variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, variables, viewstate

This is some code behind for an aspx page.
I'm not sure if I should be using public variables or a viewState

```
Partial Class madeUpName
 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
  Public vin As String = ""
  Public stk As String = ""

 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  'inside of here i use the variables
 end sub

 Protected Sub Page_Unload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
  'inside of here I also use the same variables
 end sub
```

Should I use viewState variables or public variables in my class for the page?   It seems like they both achieve the same thing.

Comment: A public variable will not work because that class is destroyed and re-created between each request.

Comment: @NateZaugg, I didn't even think about that but now that you said that it makes perfect sense.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ViewState` if you want the values to persist between postbacks.

If the values only need to exist for the lifetime of the page, regular variables will do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `ViewState` is used to persist the state of the WebForm across `PostBacks`. If you are looking to obtain values from your WebForm into your code behind, then do use `ViewState` values, otherwise you can use the `SessionState` or depending on the data you are trying to access you can use `Cookies` or even the `QueryString`. Public variables will be reset with every `PostBack` unless you save their values in the `ViewState` or the `SessionState`, etc...

More info:

[Understanding Asp.Net ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

[Best way to save variables between postbacks asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138480/best-way-to-save-varibles-between-postbacks-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

If the information is not very sensitive you can store them in hidden inputs:

`<input type="hidden" name="myvar" value="123" />`

I tend to prefer that over putting stuff in the `ViewState`. Additionally you can create accessors that make it easy to access these values later (please excuse my C# syntax):

```
public int MyValue
{
    get { return int.Parse(Request["myvar"]); }
}
```

When you can use it in your class like a property.

Otherwise you can put stuff in the `ViewState` (similarly)

```
public int MyValue
{
    get { return int.Parse(ViewState["myvar"]); }
}
```